# How to create array from variable php using loop for?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, loops, for-loop

How to create array from variable php using loop for ?

i have many variable php like

```
$number_0 = 1;
$number_1 = 2;
$number_2 = 5;
$number_3 = 2;
$number_4 = 6;
```

i want to create array like this

```
$ar = array('1','2','5','2','6');
```

but using loop for like

```
for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
$number."_".$i ====> to array
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a recomended way of doing things but:

```
$arr = array();
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    $varName = 'number_'.$i;
    $arr[] = $$varName;
}
```

Comment: I was about to ask a similar question, can you explain why it's not recommended,

The only variance in my question is that I might add new Variables and I don't want to change numbers every time I would like PHP to detect the number of variables.

Comment: variable variable names are not a good practice, generally there is always a better way of doing something than with variable-variables, but very very rarely there isn't..

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++)
    $ar[] = $i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for ($i=1;$i<7;$i++)
 {
      $ar[] = $i;
 }
```